# What should I do after finding salary information on the company fileserver?

Tags: salary, security, privacy

We have a local fileserver on premises. It appears a manager synced his cloud storage account to a folder on this server (in a location that's not very hard to find). This folder is now accessible to anyone in the company and contains an Excel file called 'Salaries', in which the salaries of the employees of a certain department are listed. This is not the first time this manager has done this - on the same server I have found a file which contains feedback and evaluations of employees.

What steps could or should I take? Do nothing and stay safe? Notify HR or Infosec (we have people dedicated to this with GDPR coming up)? Should I do this anonymously? Or maybe I should just straight up inform the manager himself?

Comment: If you report it, prepare for questions about why you are snooping through file folders in locations that are "not very hard to find."

Comment: Does your employer have a written policy about what to do when you see an issue like this?

Comment: @AffableAmbler Questions with ethical components can be on-topic here if they ask practical questions. There's usually significant overlap between ethical and professional in workplace contexts. More on that [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/453/25739). Do note that regardless of the question being on-topic or not, it's considered bad form to (partially) answer it in the comments.

Comment: Do the same thing you'd do if you accidentally saw your parents in an intimate embrace; pretend you didn't see it and never speak of it again.

Comment: @Lumberjack - If files are not meant for to be seen by me, then I shouldn't be able to find them and open them.  It's not "snooping" for me to go through and see every file out there that is available to me. That's an easy query to respond to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Be careful

You are in dangerous territory here.  You saw a file called "Salaries" and decided you should open it and see what's inside.  If you report this to INFOSEC, your decision to open the file will likely be as big a cause for concern as any careless manager storing files in the wrong folder.

In the future if you discover files that you think may contain sensitive  information, don't open them up to dig deeper.  You have rightly recognized that you have an obligation to help safeguard the confidentiality of that document, but you compromised that confidentiality when you opened the file.

Next time this happens, instead of opening the file to view the Salaries, examine the security properties of the file and **notify the "file owner"**.  If you aren't familiar with how to do this, it will be simpler to report the issue to your IT Department or Help Desk and let them handle things from there.

In this case, I would contact the Manager who saved the file, and let him know that you saw the file name and were concerned about a possible exposure.  Let him deal with it from there.

If you see a pattern of careless behavior moving forward, reporting the issue to INFOSEC is your duty, but you need to keep your own nose clean too.

Comment: Definitely need to be cautious here.  Viewing that information could get one fired.

Comment: +1 The days of "If you don't break or take, it's okay" are long over.  Excellent, well thought out advice.

Comment: I have to disagree with this.  If I can open a folder, then my assumption is that I'm allowed to have access to and see the contents within.  If I can open a file, then it's my assumption that I'm meant to be able to see the contents.  If it has confidential information, it shouldn't be safeguarded by having an ominous sounding file name.  It's supposed to be locked down. If I see it and I'm not supposed to, that's on the person who created the file, or the IT department that manages security and access.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Your assumption seems questionable. If someone left their filing cabinet or desk unlocked, would you assume that you have the right to see all documents inside it? If someone left their front door unlocked, would you assume that you have the right to wander in and look round? — Yes, confidential information _should_ have better protection than that, but I don't think that's an excuse for looking at it. Ability ≠ right.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet If I left my wallet on my desk, opened, and with some bills loose, are you free to take them? Of course not. That's clearly my wallet, on my desk, and it's my money. Your ease of access is **not** justification. There's no good reason why a random employee would reason that he should have access to a file called "Salaries".

Comment: @Nelson - that's a HORRIBLE analogy. Files aren't material objects. You also don't know what's actually in a file until you open it.  Online files and access gets set by company policy as to who can access it and who can't.  If you can see it and open it, then the company has not restricted it from your viewing or use.  If that's an error, and you find out accidentally, then it is what it is, but you should not get into any kind of jeopardy or opening a file that your employer has given you full access to.

Comment: @gidds - also a horrible analogy. A person's personal workspace is considered their personal workspace.  Shared company computer directories are SHARED, and you are supposed to access them to do your work. The company restricts who can open and use directories and files by who they want to use them. If you can open them, the working assumption is that you are meant to. If you see it's something you should not have access to, you report it, especially because it means others also probably shouldn't but can. But you don't or shouldn't get into trouble for that.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I take your point, but I'm not sure I agree with your assumption about company restrictions. _Some_ IT set-ups may indeed restrict access to _some_ directories, but I've never worked anywhere where that policy is applied completely right down to the level of every file — you often have access to things that don't directly concern you, and sometimes to things you probably shouldn't be able to see (even if that's just because someone saved a file in the wrong place by mistake). (contd…)

Comment: @PoloHoleSet No analogies are perfect, but for a shared space, how about a stationery cupboard? You may go in there regularly for new pens or whatever — but that wouldn't justify looking through the top shelf, taking down a paper file marked ‘Salaries’, opening it, and reading the contents. With a title like that, it'd be fairly clear you have no business reason for reading it, and so no justification for opening it. (Of course, many names would NOT make it as clear, and so it would be less reasonable to get into trouble — unless company policy required positive authorisation for each access.)

Comment: @gidds - but it's not just "shared space" - it's workspace, where items there are specifically accessible so the worker can work.  If there's a file in the "PolicyQATeam15" folder, and I am have specific access to that folder, and I can open the file, no sane company on the planet is doing to ding me for thinking I can open any file, no matter the name. If it wasn't meant to be there, the ones in hot water will be IT for access control, or the person who made the restricted information file, for putting in an accessible area.

Comment: I'd only get into trouble if I opened it, saw it was restricted information, said nothing and left it, as is, where anyone else who wasn't supposed to have access would still have access.

Comment: @gidds - I've worked almost exclusively where there are huge legal problems if people not supposed to have access get access (banking, financial, insurance, government health care), and there are regular audits to verify access control is in place as it should be.  Here's an analogy - If I walk around with my pants around my ankles at work, do you think my co-workers will get in trouble for seeing my behind, or will I get in trouble for showing it to everyone?

Comment: @gidds - If there is a stationary cupboard, where everyone can go for office supplies, I should not get into any trouble for rooting around in that cupboard, looking for office supplies, and opening boxes, cans and any other container that's in there.

Answer (score 13):

Report to whoever manages permissions on the folders on that server that this folder is readable by anyone and most probably shouldn't be. Do not elaborate. Let them take this from there and remove yourself from this matter.
Unless your firm employs dedicated policies and processes regarding possible internal information leaks (by your description, not very likely), the tech person will probably just silently fix the permissions and be done with it, especially if it was their fault (even indirectly).

Judging by your description, it's highly unlikely that they will be able to see that you opened the file. As an IT pro, I can attest that file access tracking facilities are a PINA to work with and eat up system resources like nobody's business. So they are not enabled save for in high security environments where it's absolutely necessary. If your environment was that, that manager couldn't have created that folder and set up cloud sync without infosec having scrunitized and authorized it in the first place (and you wouldn't know any of that, either).

Likewise, for the same reason, it's virtually impossible that it's some sort of bait or a mind game by a local Columbo. Especially in the light of the previous similar incidents involving the same person that for all intents and purposes look legitimate.

Answer (score 7):

**It could be a trap**

Realize here there is a chance you've been already caught in the *[Honeypot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing))*, and if you don't report this, you may still have to answer tough questions like why you opened the file.

Infosec loves to do things like this, whether dropping a CD in an open area with "Salaries" written on it, or perhaps in this case leaving a document in an easy to find place.  The idea around the honeypot is you see something desirable, and then do something you shouldn't (Opening this file).  This is a huge weakness for companies, because you can easily be socially engineered to give away your password and cause your company to come under attack.

In your specific case, this may well not be a trap seeing that you saw actual salary information, but you should be forewarned that not everything is as it seems.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Best answer here!

Comment: because it's not a trap, given salary information was there.

Comment: And you know this information is accurate and valid... how? @bharal

Comment: well, he asked about it. also he can probably check against his own salary

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm down-voting. If I can open a file, then that's not something I shouldn't be doing, because if I'm not supposed to, then I shouldn't have access. If I see something, AFTER opening that makes me say "I shouldn't be able to see this," then I report it, but the baseline "can I open this?" answer is - "I don't know, CAN you open it?"

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Interesting concept, have you tried this with your neighbors mail?

Comment: @DavidS - My neighbor doesn't specifically give me access and permission to his mailbox to do my work.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Before computers, people walked into offices and congregated together to work. In those offices, an individual has physical access to a great many things they should not access. They don't have permission to access it, so they shouldn't, despite nothing physically stopping them. You seem to think that the rules change because the areas you can access are digital. Your argument on the digital side suggests your neighbor needs to lock his mailbox to prevent you from viewing his mail, and his lack of a lock is granting you permission.

Comment: @DavidS - and..... so what? Before electric lights, they used whale oil lamps. Interesting trivia, but not relevant here.  The OP didn't ask about a pre-computer scenario. OP isn't asking about physical file cabinets, rooms and folders.  OP is asking about computer files, which DO have access controls built in, which is how any office environment in the past 20 years or so has functioned. The rules ARE different for digital record keeping. Back in the Stone Age, if you weren't supposed to see a file, they'd write something like that on the folder. Now they restrict access. Name is irrelevant.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet You're conflating access and permission. They are not the same. You may have access to something you do not have permission to access. It is your duty to only access that of which you have permission to access, regardless of what other controls are in place. Permission is a control, and employee self-governance is a control. I'm not sure what rules you think change, but you're literally saying that a file folder that says "For CEO eyes only" with a file in it, one printed left in the office and another left on the company-wide shared drive, reading the digital copy is fine.

Comment: @DavidS - That's because, for access to online files and directories, that access is granted by granting permissions. Literally.  And, yes. If I'm not supposed to see the contents of an online folder, I should not be ABLE to see it. Again, the problem is not me for reading what I have been given access to, and, simultaneously permission to. The problem is with whomever is incorrectly GRANTING that access.

Answer (score 2):

In a previous life I wrote/supported a program that was used to calculate salaries and bonuses for employees.  For this I needed to get a feed from HR during salary review season.  The file was supposed to have masked/encrypted fields that were unpacked in my program and only viewable by a set of users and their access level.

One year, the program blew up when importing.  It turns out the HR clerk that pulled the data that year didn't use the program written (that encrypted the data) but instead ran a Peoplesoft SQR which put the data into plain readable ASCII text.  When I opened the file to investigate I could see everyone's current salary.

I immediately notified my supervisor.  INFOSEC and HR were notified.  My manager notified senior management.  Then the CD the data was written to was placed in a secure disposal system by my manager.  This had some major ramifications but as we (me and my boss) covered our buts it was others (the HR person) were the ones disciplined.

You can't be too safe here.  Notify your boss.

Comment: A key difference, here:  You were AUTHORIZED to look at that data.  The OP was not.

Comment: Actually I wasn't.  That's the reason is was masked.

Comment: I understand you both, and so I feel compelled to build a bridge across the gap of understanding.  Please forgive me for butting in my nose, but what @WesleyLong was trying to say is that you were authorized to open the file.  Your discovery of the non-encrypted data did not come about as a result of your inappropriate behavior.  In the case of OP, his choice to open the file will likely reflect poorly on him, whereas your choice to open the file was expected.

Comment: @Lumberjack - you're right.  I probably should have said that bednarjm was authorized to access the provided file, whereas the OP was not authorized to access the file he discovered.

Comment: just seems to be an anecdote?