# A colleague found on our LAN all employee's resumes/CV. Is this a data breach?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy

I work in an office in the UK with about 120 staff.
We all have access to the "public drive" which is a LAN for us to share work. There's also thing on there like pics from the Christmas party, etc. It's pretty big.

A colleague recently told me that he found a folder full of every employee's resume/CV. Some he didn't recognise, so they must be people who applied and didn't get a job. He also told me things about other people's previous work. 
I'd also heard another colleague say that he once found his own interview feedback, with comments and everything.

Does this breach data protection laws?

I should note that my line of work makes in necessary for my employees to know my phone number, though probably not my address. But what about the other bits of information. Fair enough its not personal data, but isn't it unfair to have this public?

Note: I'm not asking if the person who found this information committed a data breach, but if the company did by putting it on the public drive in the first place.

Comment: Are comments/feedback also personal? Ive just found a spreadsheet with some current employers name on. Comments include "Came across enthusiastic. Did well on case study" etc. These look like internal comments. Not necessarily passed on to the candidate

Comment: @OnlineUser02094 This is not personal information however should still be kept private from other employees

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/109822/what-should-i-do-after-finding-salary-information-on-the-company-fileserver

Comment: Update: I only went through stuff with peoples name I didnt recognise to respect the colleagues I know, and I only skimmed through so that I can see what kind of information is on there. 
I have since reported it to one of the I.T. managers who said they will remove it.

Comment: This is absolutely not company-specific

Comment: I think you should ask this in Law stack exchange, since your question boils down to "Is it legal to...".  That's not really what The Workplace is for, which is why this got closed.  If your question asked whether what the company did was standard practice in the workforce, that would be on topic I think.  Or if you asked how to decide what, if anything, you should do about this situation, that would also be on topic.  But not whether it's legal.  So this question, as worded, is just in the wrong place on stack exchange.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, to answer your question of whether this is a data breach, **it absolutely is per GDPR.** The [GDPR definition](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-4-gdpr/) of a "personal data breach" is the below. Personal data is defined broadly to include data that identifies a natural person using elements such as name and factors specific to the economic identity of a person. I interpret "economic" to include employment history.

> personal data breach’ means a breach of security leading to the accidental or unlawful destruction, loss, alteration, unauthorised disclosure of, or access to, personal data transmitted, stored or otherwise processed;

You have not asked for this, but I will share with you some best information security best practices that hopefully can mitigate a similar incident occurring in the future.

> **Least privileged access**

[Least privileged access](https://www.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/principles/least-privilege) means that only people who need access to a particular asset (such as this data) to perform their job are granted access. Apparently in this case, this best practice was not followed because users having no legitimate business need obtained access to highly sensitive data they should not have had access to. You probably do not know for certain how long this data was exposed on the network share, and **whether this data was already exfiltrated / otherwise misused.**

Going forward after this incident, it is probably worthwhile to **perform a through access review of users** and exactly what access they have to data. To go along with this activity, designate a limited number of  data custodians whose duty it is to safeguard access to such data. To obtain management buy - in, you can use this incident and its potential impact to company (fines, lawsuits etc.). Assuming management is rational and reasonable, **they should care.**

> **Data labelling and classification**

It is best security practice to [classify data](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/199/final) based on its sensitivity, with one consideration of sensitivity being the potential adverse impact if it were to be compromised (as it was in your case). Your company is fairly small now at 120 employees, but as it expands, maintaining proper governance of data will tend to be more important. Depending on your standing and role in the company, suggesting improving the classification of data may be something to explore with company management / your manager.

This does not have to complex effort, and a data classification scheme as simple as public vs confidential data may suffice. Regardless any decisions should be documented and signed off on by management in a **policy document** made known to all stakeholders.

> **Security incident response and data exfiltration detection**

In this case, the [security incident](https://www.us-cert.gov/government-users/compliance-and-reporting/incident-definition) was brought to your attention by your colleague. Informal methods of notification may work when organizations are immature, but as companies grow, it's almost always beneficial to establish formal procedures for identifying, containing, remediating, and reporting security incidents to company management from my work experience. As part of the security incident response procedures, there should be means, such as DLP, to detect the unauthorized transmission or disclosure of company data.

> **Encryption of sensitive data**

Depending on your threat model, the value of this data to management, and technological capability of your company IT, you may want to think about encrypting such sensitive data, so even if individuals gain unauthorized access to it, they cannot read it. If you decide to go this route, below are some best implementation practices:

1. Use a secure encryption protocol such as AES or RSA using a long private key length to make decryption by malicious actors as difficult as possible.
2. Establish procedures and controls to safeguard the decryption key such as through split knowledge or control
3. Rotate the encryption / decryption key periodically or **whenever you suspects its compromised**
4. Keep access to the encryption key to the minimum number of custodians that need access to it to perform their job duties.

Answer (score 11):

As you are based in the UK this is a huge issue for your company especially with the new GDPR changes.

Any personal information should be protected including, Address, Phone Numbers and even any employment history.

Other employees should most definitely not be able to access personal comments, interview comments and especially not personal details that should be secure. Report this to your manager/HR straight away otherwise you're going to have a massive issue if any of this is released outside of the company...

As you mentioned you can see the comments/feedback on a spreadsheet. Although not personal... This could cause some other potential issues within the company e.g. bullying, complaints and just unnecessary discussion in general.

Comment: Report to the IT team and the person responible for GDPR immediately, as IT will need to take steps to lock down access.

Comment: @AdzzzUK No, the IT team has already failed. Report to legal / HR and CC someone high up.

Comment: @rath, the IT team need to take immediate action by locking the folder permissions down tight and immediately preventing anyone else from gaining access to the folders.  That needs to happen immediately.  Also, the HR team have been part of the breach by storing the data in this folder themselves and potentially assuming that only they could see it.  I do agree that HR and up the chain should be informed however.

Comment: @rath I wouldn't say the IT team failed. There is a good chance they have no idea whats on the network drive. They were probably told we need network storage. This is an issue with whoever put them not, not the IT department.

Comment: Its probably worth mentioning that we are an I.T. firm lol it has since been reported.

Comment: The company will 100% be legally required to report this to the relevant overseeing agency. This is a pretty massive breach. Personal data about employment history is especially sensitive anyways.

Comment: Lets not forget that personal data should not be kept past (I think) 30 days after its last use. Paraprashing here, but the point is: The resumes of people that applied should not be kept past this period. Anyone feel free to correct me here, not an expert.

Comment: @BlackMagic There are various requirements for different data; some which you cannot delete before a certain period of time (6 years for employment records). It's unfortunately not a situation where a rule of thumb can be applied - whoever oversees GDPR compliance at the office needs to be made aware and make the specific decision based on what data is held.